# Defining a method with equals signs in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to create a User class that would store only hashed password

```
class User
  # Password should be stored only as hash in @password_hash,
  # crypted by that function:
  def self.crypt(password)
    # Returns password hash
  end

  # Crypt password and store it in @password_hash
  def password=(str)
    @password_hash = crypt(str)
  end

  # Crypt given password and compare it with stored @password_hash
  def password==(str)
    @password_hash == crypt(str)
  end
end

me = User.new
me.password = 'qwerty'

if me.password == 'qwerty'
  puts 'Ok'
else
  puts 'Error'
end
```

But I get a `syntax error, unexpected tEQ, expecting '\n' or ';'` on 14 line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't define a method called `password==`. Assignments are special; comparisons are not. If you really want to use `User.password == "something"` syntax, this is the way to do it:

```
class User
  attr_reader :password
  def password=(str)
    @password = Password.new(str)
  end

  class Password < String
    def encrypt(str)
      "foo" + str # TODO make stronger
    end

    def initialize(str)
      super(encrypt(str))
    end

    def ==(other)
      super(encrypt(other))
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
def == str
   @password_hash == crypt(str)
end
```

Also [take a look](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Comparable.html) at the `Comparable` module.

Comment: I don't want to affect class' equality method, but as one way to solve the problem it will work.

Comment: Erm, I'm sure it's a typo, but... `<=>` is an integer function, `==` is boolean; I'm pretty sure you don't want the result of one to be the result of the other.